# Check if Radio Button is Checked and if Value Matches

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button, checked

Wracking my brain trying to figure this out. I'm not the greatest with Jquery but know enough to kinda get by. Right now I am trying to develop something that will check if a radio button in a group is checked and then to see if its value matches so it can then show the correct corresponding section. I have a crude JSFiddle made that is close to my staging site's set up.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <label>Oak</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='Oak_0' checked="checked">

    <label>Brown Maple</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='Brown Maple_1'>

    <label>Cherry</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='Cherry_2'>

    <label>Quartersawn White Oak</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='Quartersawn White Oak_3'>

    <label>Hard Maple</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='Hard Maple_4'>

    <label>Hickory</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='Hickory_5'>

    <!-- Many Others... -->
</div>
<div class="stains-container">
  <div class="oak-stains-div">
    <h4>Oak</h4>
    <label>Michael's Cherry</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Rich Tobacco</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Dark Knight</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <!-- Many Others... -->
  </div>
  <div class="b-maple-stains-div">
    <h4>Brown Maple</h4>
    <label>Michael's Cherry</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Rich Tobacco</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Dark Knight</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <!-- Many Others... -->
  </div>
  <div class="cherry-stains-div">
    <h4>Cherry</h4>
    <label>Michael's Cherry</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Rich Tobacco</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Dark Knight</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <!-- Many Others... -->
  </div>
  <div class="qswo-stains-div">
    <h4>QSWO</h4>
    <label>Michael's Cherry</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Rich Tobacco</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Dark Knight</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <!-- Many Others... -->
  </div>
  <div class="h-maple-stains-div">
    <h4>Hard Maple</h4>
    <label>Michael's Cherry</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Rich Tobacco</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Dark Knight</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <!-- Many Others... -->
  </div>
  <div class="hickory-stains-div">
    <h4>Hickory</h4>
    <label>Michael's Cherry</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Rich Tobacco</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Dark Knight</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <!-- Many Others... -->
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
// Create Variables
    var stains = $(".stains-container");
    // Check if Oak is checked
    var $oakchecked = $("input.b-maple-stains, input.cherry-stains, input.qswo-stains, input.h-maple-stains, input.hickory-stains");
    var $oakactive = $(".b-maple-stains-div li, .cherry-stains-div li, .qswo-stains-div li, .h-maple-stains-div li, .hickory-stains-div li");
    // Check if B. Maple is checked
    var $bmaplechecked = $("input.oak-stains, input.cherry-stains, input.qswo-stains, input.h-maple-stains, input.hickory-stains");
    var $bmapleactive = $(".oak-stains-div li, .cherry-stains-div li, .qswo-stains-div li, .h-maple-stains-div li, .hickory-stains-div li");
    // Check if Cherry is checked
    var $cherrychecked = $("input.oak-stains, input.b-maple-stains, input.qswo-stains, input.h-maple-stains, input.hickory-stains");
    var $cherryactive = $(".oak-stains-div li, .b-maple-stains-div li, .qswo-stains-div li, .h-maple-stains-div li, .hickory-stains-div li");
    // Check if QSWO is checked
    var $qswochecked = $("input.oak-stains, input.b-maple-stains, input.cherry-stains, input.h-maple-stains, input.hickory-stains");
    var $qswoactive = $(".oak-stains-div li, .b-maple-stains-div li, .cherry-stains-div li, .h-maple-stains-div li, .hickory-stains-div li");
    // Check if H. Maple is checked
    var $hmaplechecked = $("input.oak-stains, input.b-maple-stains, input.cherry-stains, input.qswo-stains, input.hickory-stains");
    var $hmapleactive = $(".oak-stains-div li, .b-maple-stains-div li, .cherry-stains-div li, .qswo-stains-div li, .hickory-stains-div li");
    // Check if Hickory is checked
    var $hickorychecked = $("input.oak-stains, input.b-maple-stains, input.cherry-stains, input.qswo-stains, input.h-maple-stains");
    var $hickoryactive = $(".oak-stains-div li, .b-maple-stains-div li, .cherry-stains-div li, .qswo-stains-div li, .h-maple-stains-div li");


// Check if a button is pre-selected and if its value matches
var radio_buttons = $("input[name='tmcp_radio_0']");
    if( radio_buttons.is(":checked") && /^Oak_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
        alert("OAK is selected");
        $(".oak-stains-div").show();
        $oakchecked.prop('checked', false);
        $oakactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
    } else if( radio_buttons.is(":checked") && /^Brown Maple_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
        alert("B MAPLE is selected");
        $(".b-maple-stains-div").show();
        $bmaplechecked.prop('checked', false);
        $bmapleactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
    } else if( radio_buttons.is(":checked") && /^Cherry_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
        alert("CHERRY is selected");
        $(".cherry-stains-div").show();
        $cherrychecked.prop('checked', false);
        $cherryactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
    } else if( radio_buttons.is(":checked") && /^Quartersawn White Oak_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
        alert("QSWO is selected");
        $(".qswo-stains-div").show();
        $qswochecked.prop('checked', false);
        $qswoactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
    } else if( radio_buttons.is(":checked") && /^Hard Maple_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
        alert("H MAPLE is selected");
        $(".h-maple-stains-div").show();
        $hmaplechecked.prop('checked', false);
        $hmapleactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
    } else if( radio_buttons.is(":checked") && /^Hickory_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
        alert("HICKORY is selected");
        $(".hickory-stains-div").show();
        $hickorychecked.prop('checked', false);
        $hickoryactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
    } else if( radio_buttons.is(":not(:checked)")) {
        alert("NOTHING is selected");
        $(".stains-container").hide();
    } 
    // Check if Oak is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change',function(){
        if ( /^Oak_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
            stains.show();
            $(".oak-stains-div").show();
            $oakchecked.prop('checked', false);
            $oakactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
        }  else {
            $(".oak-stains-div").hide();
        }
    });

    // Check if B. Maple is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change',function(){
        if ( /^Brown Maple_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
            stains.show();
            $(".b-maple-stains-div").show();
            $bmaplechecked.prop('checked', false);
            $bmapleactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
        } else {
            $(".b-maple-stains-div").hide();
        }
    });

    // Check if Cherry is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change',function(){
        if ( /^Cherry_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
            stains.show();
            $(".cherry-stains-div").show();
            $cherrychecked.prop('checked', false);
            $cherryactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
        } else {
            $(".cherry-stains-div").hide();
        }
    });

    // Check if QSWO is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change',function(){
        if ( /^Quartersawn White Oak_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
            stains.show();
            $(".qswo-stains-div").show();
            $qswochecked.prop('checked', false);
            $qswoactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
        } else {
            $(".qswo-stains-div").hide();
        }
    });

    // Check if Hard Maple is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change',function(){
        if ( /^Hard Maple_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
            stains.show();
            $(".h-maple-stains-div").show();
            $hmaplechecked.prop('checked', false);
            $hmapleactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
        } else {
            $(".h-maple-stains-div").hide();
        }
    });

    // Check if Hickory is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change',function(){
        if ( /^Hickory_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
            stains.show();
            $(".hickory-stains-div").show();
            $hickorychecked.prop('checked', false);
            $hickoryactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
        } else {
            $(".hickory-stains-div").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/amishdirect/h94c7rsw/5/

The section I am struggling with is having it check if an input is "checked" AND if its value matches. The area `/^Oak_\d$/.test($(this).val())` is because depending on the order the value changes (IE: Oak_0, Oak_1, Oak_2, etc). I'm trying to it match the input no matter where it is. Right now I am stuck because I'm struggling to have it check for both and return the correct stuff. I will also say the JS is crude and most likely can be improved and condensed. This is just what I have so I am thankful for any suggestions to improving it as well!

Comment: What do you think `$(this)` is in your code? It's no in a click event handler, so it's not the button they clicked on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an attribute selector.

```
var oak_checked = $(":radio[value^=oak]").is(":checked");
```

Your code doesn't work because `this` is not the checked button. Testing `.is(":checked")` doesn't change the value of `this` to whatever button that found that might be checked.

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Not sure why I overlooked the selector here and not elsewhere. The tricky thing with this is the values change due to a plugin we're using so I'm trying to make it as dummy proof as positive just in case. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to use a bit better class names to help selectors. Consider the following.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/zpwc92rv/24/

**HTML**

```
<ul class="bases">
  <li>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='top radiogroup' value='oak'>
    <label>Oak</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='top radiogroup' value='b-maple'>
    <label>Brown Maple</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='top radiogroup' value='cherry'>
    <label>Cherry</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='top radiogroup' value='qswo'>
    <label>Quartersawn White Oak</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='top radiogroup' value='h-maple'>
    <label>Hard Maple</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='top radiogroup' value='hickory'>
    <label>Hickory</label>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="stains">
  <div class="oak stain">
    <h4>Oak</h4>
    <label>Michael's Cherry</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>
    <label>Rich Tobacco</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>
    <label>Dark Knight</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>
    <!-- Many Others... -->
  </div>
  <div class="b-maple stain">
    <h4>Brown Maple</h4>
    <label>Michael's Cherry</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>
    <label>Rich Tobacco</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>
    <label>Dark Knight</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>
    <!-- Many Others... -->
  </div>
  <div class="cherry stain">
    <h4>Cherry</h4>
    <label>Michael's Cherry</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>
    <label>Rich Tobacco</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>
    <label>Dark Knight</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>
    <!-- Many Others... -->
  </div>
  <div class="qswo stain">
    <h4>QSWO</h4>
    <label>Michael's Cherry</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>
    <label>Rich Tobacco</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>
    <label>Dark Knight</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>
    <!-- Many Others... -->
  </div>
  <div class="h-maple stain">
    <h4>Hard Maple</h4>
    <label>Michael's Cherry</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>
    <label>Rich Tobacco</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>
    <label>Dark Knight</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>
    <!-- Many Others... -->
  </div>
  <div class="hickory stain">
    <h4>Hickory</h4>
    <label>Michael's Cherry</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>
    <label>Rich Tobacco</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>
    <label>Dark Knight</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_1" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>
    <!-- Many Others... -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  function hideAll() {
    $(".stains .stain").hide();
  }

  function uncheckAll() {
    $(".stain input:checked").prop("checked", false);
  }

  hideAll();
  $(".bases input").on("change", function(e) {
    $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
    var s = $(this).val();
    hideAll();
    uncheckAll();
    $(".stain." + s).show();
  });
  $(".bases input:first").trigger("click");
});
```

As you can see, it can be easier to hide all the items, and then show just the needed items based on the `value` that is clicked upon.